# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

Got a crash

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

in line `if(!app.settings.currentAuthToken.length)` where `Settings` is a class that has `NSUserDefaults` public property. `CurrentAuthToken` is a string property. In the logic of app this property can be changed and read in different threads. May it cause this crash?

Here is an interface of `Settings` class:

```
@interface Settings : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSUserDefaults* defaults;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* currentUserId;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* currentAuthToken;

@end
```

Here is a code of methods inside of `Settings` class:

```
@synthesize defaults;
@dynamic currentUserId,currentAuthToken;

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults synchronize];`        

    }
    return self;
}

-(NSMethodSignature*)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector{
    if ([NSStringFromSelector(aSelector) hasPrefix:@"set"])
        return [super methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(setter:)];
    return [super methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(getter)];
}

-(id)getter{return nil;}
-(void)setter:(id)value{}

-(void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation{
    NSString* key = NSStringFromSelector(anInvocation.selector);
    if ([key hasPrefix:@"set"]){
        key = [key substringFromIndex:3];
        key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[key substringToIndex:1] lowercaseString],[key substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, key.length-1)]];
        key = [key substringToIndex:key.length-1];

        __unsafe_unretained id argument;
        [anInvocation getArgument:&argument atIndex:2];

        [defaults setObject:argument forKey:key];
    }else{
            id returnValue = [defaults objectForKey:key];
            [anInvocation setReturnValue:&returnValue];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the member variables as declared in the Settings class

Comment: What is the advantage of this low-level synthesizing over implicit synthesized properties provided since Xcode 4 or 5?

Comment: @vadian This was done to make reading and wring to value from NSUserDefaults more elegant.

Comment: Elegance is a matter of taste ;-)

Comment: Hey.. were you able to solve this crash?